# why need explicit self inside of initialize() ruby

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why 'attributes=' inside of initialize should have prefix self.

'name' method doesn't need to have prefix self to call 'attributes' method

```
class A
 attr_accessor :attributes

  def initialize attrs ={}
    self.attributes = attrs
  end

  def name 
    puts attributes
  end
end

a = {"name" => "someone"}
b = A.new a

b.name
```

output {"name" => "someone"}

if `self.attributes = attrs` change to `attributes = attrs`
output gonna be nil

Comment: This all depends on how Ruby sees `attributes=` in the body of your `initialize` method. Without `self` to force it to be a method call it's often interpreted as a variable assignment.

Comment: Not "often". *Always* `foo = bar` is *always* assigning to a local variable named `foo`. In fact, that's how Ruby distinguishes between local variable references and method calls: `foo` is a local variable reference if and only if an assignment `foo = bar` has been parsed before.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `attributes = attrs` you will just assign `attrs` to the local variable `attributes` just as you could assign `attrs` to `some_other_var`. By prepending `attributes` with `self.` you specify that the accessor needs to be used.

Comment: I thought attributes= defined by attr_accessor, how to explain   def name puts attributes end.

Comment: Calling the get `attributes` accessor does a lookup, first if there is locally a variable named `attributes`, if there is not it looks for an instance method named `attributes`, in this case it will find it as you have defined it with `attr_accessor`. For assignment with `attributes=` there is no way to distinguish between local variable assignment and the instance setter method which is why you need to disambiguate it with the `self.attributes=`